# WPF displaying correctly only when debugging

Tags: wpf, debugging

I'm fairly new to WPF and am writing a program that sends/receives messages to/from a wireless device that communicates through the serial port. I'm stuck on one particular section where the GUI is not displaying as expected... but when I put in breakpoints and debug, the data is correctly displayed. How do I debug something that works correctly in debug mode?

The gist of it is, I send 2 separate messages to the serial port device in order to populate two different parts of my GUI.

```
private void getDeviceIntoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    IDList.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //send message to serial port device to get ID#
    }));

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    SettingsList.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //send message to serial port device to get settings
    }));
}
```

Then my event handler should receive each separate message and display to the GUI:

```
private void DisplayID(string data)
{
    IDList.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //add received ID to ID list
    }));

}

private void DisplaySettings(string data)
{
    SettingsList.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //add received setting to settings list
    }));
}
```

If I only send one of the two messages, it somehow works, but if I send both messages, neither portion of the GUI is updated. Again, the confusing part is that they both display correctly when I'm debugging. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what `Thread.Sleep(100)` does?  You barely see it changing because that's only 100 ms.  Additionally, if you are sleeping the UI thread, none of the controls will update because they are all sleeping.  Once it's done sleeping it's already getting new information to update with.

Comment: We need more information. In what way does it not display correctly? Can you provide screenshots? Does it work in a debug build without the debugger? What about if it's in the debugger without any breakpoints?

Comment: It seems like a timing issue rather than a WPF-specific issue.  I would only send the second message after you received a response for the first message.  You also don't need to use the `Dispatcher` unless you're communicating with the UI thread from a different thread.

Comment: @RyanEmerle, my workaround was to send the 2nd message once I had the first response, but I wasn't sure if that was good practice. Thanks to those who responded; I will try doing without the sleep and messing with it a little more, then send screenshots if I'm still unsuccessful. Thanks again!